# how can i get the total number of quantity via workflow

Tags: related-list, quote, help

I need to get the total number of quantity via workflow. I created a workflow that will get the quantity but it only returns one quantity of the product in my products related list. What i need is the totality of all of the quantity that i have in my products related list. Please help and respect post.

If It cannot be done by workflow, what other approach will give the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the fact that you want the total quantity of the products on the opportunity object.

What you need to do is create a `roll-up summary field` between opportunity and product and aggregate on the sum of all the products' quantity. This is all standard Salesforce functionality and could be achieved with a couple of clicks.